# Как можно вставить массив из JSON в обычный массив?

Tags: php, массивы, json

С помощью PHP кода

```
$client = new RandomORGClient('10fbcd24-2628-4ae0-ab50-0160e1ce5ae1');

$data = $client->generateSignedIntegers(1, 1, 60);
$arr = array();
foreach($data as $randomInt) {
    array_push($arr, ($randomInt));
}
$random_arr = json_encode($arr[1]);
var_dump(json_encode($arr[1]));
```

Получаю вот такой массив:

```
"{"random":{"method":"generateSignedIntegers","hashedApiKey":"FZSXJR+2P+umSj1UIOvBEc3RpYuwh8ZQfqppk8O5froIsgTlcPWRmoYkKzLB07cCs4TXgMcZS+MduDyF0RK9+Q==","n":1,"min":1,"max":60,"replacement":true,"base":10,"data":[9],"completionTime":"2015-10-03 15:32:01Z","serialNumber":408},"signature":"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","bitsUsed":6,"bitsLeft":247666,"requestsLeft":610,"advisoryDelay":0}"
```

Хочу теперь добавить весь этот массив в другой массив, с помощью php делаю так:

```
$array = array('id' => $id_lot, 'time' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), 'winner' => array('login' => $_SESSION['personaname'], 'url' => $_SESSION['steamid'], 'image'=> $_SESSION['avatarmedium'], 'place' => '31', 'random' => $random_arr));
```

Добавил, правда как строку и в значение... :(
Вот что вышло:
[image]

Что должно выйти:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIPcW.png]

Каким образом можно сделать, чтобы эта строка json вставлялась как продолжение в массиве $array ? Чтобы передать потом его в JS.. В консоли браузера на 2м скриншоте попробовал показать, как это будет выглядеть. А то он пишет его в значение и все тут...

Comment: Используйте `json_decode()` для получения массива из `JSON` строки

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3b6a2d20be64c01ded5fb8d63130b0a88c96696d Вот песочница для Вашего решения. Как бы нормально переводит строку в массив

Comment: Да и если Вы используете новые версии РНР, то для объявления массива используйте `[]`. И `json_decode/json_encode` работает с массивами любой вложенности

Comment: @RomanKozin вам спасибо большое, но если я использую decode, то у меня просто ошибка в файле вылетает. Сейчас попробую сделать decode а потом циклом значения нужные мне вытаскивать. но даже не представляю, сколько сейчас париться буду. но суть я понял, что нужно сделать. скоро напишу о результате, если сработает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо Ваш `$random_arr` привести к виду обычного массива:

```
$random_arr = json_decode($random_arr,true);
```

второй параметр нужен для того, чтобы получить ассоциативный массив, по умолчанию `json_decode` приводит `JSON` к `stdObject` и тогда обращение к элементам происходит через `->название_параметра`. Если выставлен второй параметр в значение `true`, тогда через `['название_параметра']`.

После приведения типа, просто добавляем наш `$random_arr` в конечный массив

```
$array = array('id' => $id_lot,
'time' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), 
'winner' => array('login' => $_SESSION['personaname'], 
'url' => $_SESSION['steamid'], 
'image'=> $_SESSION['avatarmedium'], 
'place' => '31', 
'random' => $random_arr)   //вот наш массив
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Устал париться с json, решил все вручную вывести.

```
            $client = new RandomORGClient('-----------------------------');

                $data = $client->generateSignedIntegers(1, 1, $maxUsers);
                $arr = array();
                foreach($data as $randomInt) {
                    array_push($arr, ($randomInt));
                }
                $x_method = $arr[1]->random->method;
                $x_replacement = $arr[1]->random->replacement;
                $x_serialNumber = $arr[1]->random->serialNumber;
                $x_hashedApiKey = $arr[1]->random->hashedApiKey;
                $x_n = $arr[1]->random->n;
                $x_min = $arr[1]->random->min;
                $x_max = $arr[1]->random->max;
                $x_base = $arr[1]->random->base;
                $x_completionTime = $arr[1]->random->completionTime;
                $x_signature = $arr[1]->signature;
                $x_bitsUsed = $arr[1]->bitsUsed;
                $x_bitsLeft = $arr[1]->bitsLeft;
                $x_data = $arr[1]->random->data[0];
                $x_requestsLeft = $arr[1]->requestsLeft;
                $x_advisoryDelay = $arr[1]->advisoryDelay;
```